# How do i clean up a dynamic array of linked lists?

Tags: linked-list, destructor

I am writing a data structure.  It contains a struct Node.
The Node has a static array and a pointer to the next Node.
Then there is a struct Bar. This struct is a linked list of Nodes.
And wrapping it all up is the class Foo which has a dynamic array of Bars.
So far it is working as i want it to. But i dont know how to clean up after Foos lifetime is over.
Could anyone help me?

```cpp
class Foo{
    struct Node{};
    struct Bar{ 
        Node *head = nullptr;
        ...
        void free_Bar(){
            Node *current = this->head;
            Node *next = nullptr;

            while(current != nullptr){
                next = current->next;
                delete current;
                current = next;
            }
            this->head = nullptr;
        }

        ~Bar(){
            free_Bar();
        }
    };

    ...

    Bar *table;
    ...



    ~Foo{     //What do i tell the destructor of Foo so that everything is deleted?
        ??? 

    }
};
```

Comment: Read a [good C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html), the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and be aware of the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html). You could use [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and take inspiration from the source code of [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) or [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: Compile your C++ code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your executable